# localStorage clearing when I use split()

Tags: javascript

I want to create an array of names based on localStorage variable called "names". I use the String.split() to detect a new line which seems to work well, but not if I refresh the page more than once.

```
var names = localStorage.names;     

if (!names) {
textArea.style.display = "block";
mybutton.style.display = "block";
} else {
    textSplit = localStorage.names.split(/\n/); 
    copyInput1.innerHTML = textSplit[0];
    copyInput2.innerHTML = textSplit[1];
    copyInput3.innerHTML = textSplit[2];
}

document.getElementById("textArea").focus();

var showText = function() {
    var text = textArea.value;      
    localStorage.names = text;
    textSplit = localStorage.names.split(/\n/);     
    copyInput1.innerHTML = textSplit[0];
    copyInput2.innerHTML = textSplit[1];
    copyInput3.innerHTML = textSplit[2];
}

mybutton.onclick = showText;
clearbutton.onclick = localStorage.clear();
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: So what happens if you refresh more than once?

Comment: Where are `textArea`, `mybutton`, `textSplit `, `copyInput_` and `clearButton` defined?

Comment: textArea, mybutton, copyInput_ defined at the start of js file, mybutton and clear Button at the end.  textSplit defined within the functions as seen. It works with one refresh, but on the second all clears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are executing `clear()` on `localStorage` which explains why it clears:

```
clearbutton.onclick = localStorage.clear();
```

Change this to:

```
clearbutton.onclick = localStorage.clear;
```

This way you're referencing the function instead.